# Entity Framework Caching with the Repository Pattern

Tags: .net, caching, frameworks, entity

If I want to implement caching when I am using the repository pattern and the Entity Framework, couldn't I just do some simple logic outside of the Entity Framework to handle the caching?

E.g.

```
if(Cache[ProductsKey] != null)
{
    return ConvertToProducts(Cache[ProductsKey]);
}
else
{
    var products = repository.Products;
    Cache[ProductsKey] =  products;
    return products;
}
```

It seems like a lot of people are over-complicating this. Or is doing it this way going to be limiting in some way?

Comment: Entity Framework already contains identity map which caches local copy of object, secondly, you can treat them all objects simply as a list and store them in any dictionary. You have to be more specific to what exactly you are looking for, the example you have given has no problem as long as you are just going to display items.

Comment: Have a look [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/orm-9780596520281-01-21.aspx)

Comment: @Akash So is there really no need to do caching then?

Comment: Yes as long as your object context is alive, all children are cached in it anyway.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I prefer my repository to be clean. I prefer **implementing caching in my service layer** if needed.

So i **100% agree with your sample**. Your repository returns products (by running query) and you can *cache it or not* in other layers.

P.S.: I assume that you start your object context when it's needed(session start) and dispose it when session ends.

Comment: Caching entities does not work with lazy loading in ASP.Net as the DbContext or ObjectContext that the entity is attached to is disposed as soon as the request ends.

Comment: @mohas yes. Lazy loading is not an option if you cache your entities.

Answer (score 4):

It is better to cash the entire `ObjectContext` which is here the (Repository).

Use the `Session_Start` and `Session_End` to initialize and dispose the object respectively.